# How can I make itunes work with bluetooth media buttons on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, itunes, gestures

If I am listening to music on itunes on windows 10 and I press any of the media buttons on my bluetooth headset such as play/pause, next, prev.

It does not send the commands to itunes. Instead it sends it to the last process that output audio that isn't itunes. Such as my browser.

How can I make itunes work with the bluetooth media buttons?

Comment: This sounds like a driver issue, and if so, there's likely nothing you can do other than alert the OEM/driver developer of the issue

Comment: Which media buttons are you using?

Comment: @JW0914 I tested it again and the bluetooth media buttons do work, but only if firefox and chrome does not have any media playing such as a youtube video or mp3 song.

If I play any audio through my browsers. They steal focus for the bluetooth button input and don't give it up until the tabs that played the media are closed. Even if I switch the window back to itunes. 

Any idea how to have itunes take priority if music is played more recently than the browser audio?

Comment: @John if there are no options to control this in the Control Panel, Settings, or the BT driver settings for the BT headset, it sounds like a driver issue and how an application is programmed to use the driver; if the latter is the case, it may be worth your time to file a big report with Apple, Google, Microsoft, and Mozilla _(copy/paste the same across all four)_, as that's really odd behavior and doesn't seem like it could be as intended programming.